# How to get mutable reference of struct(constrained with lifetime) field?

Tags: rust, lifetime

To be frank, I dont know if title perfectly describes my problem. 
I myself dont know what is the problem. 
Im getting errors anyway.

My Code is

```
// main.rs
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<'a> {
    f1: B<'a>,
    f2: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B<'a> {
    f1: Vec<&'a str>,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            f1: B::new(),
            f2: 0,
        }
    }

    fn set_f1(&mut self, b: B<'a>) {
        self.f1 = b;
    }

    fn get_f1(&mut self) -> &mut B {
        &mut self.f1
    }

    fn execute(&mut self) {
        self.get_f1().set_f1()
    }
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            f1: vec!["string literal"],
        }
    }

    fn set_f1(&mut self) {
        self.f1 = vec!["changed"]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    let mut b = B::new();
    let mut b2 = B::new();
    a.set_f1(b); // for testing
    a.set_f1(b2); // for testing

    a.execute();

    // a.get_f1().set_f1(); this is working here but not in method execute. Why?
}
```

This is the perfect sample duplicate(simpler version, ignoring all other fields and methods) code.  
I have no choice other than using string literals `&str` instead of `String` as its easier for pattern matching.

So, I introduced lifetimes. I dont know if its correct or not or is one of best practices.

I need a field `f1` of `A` is a mutable so i could change the `f1` field of `B`. 
How can this be implemented?

I tried in some ways, here is the link for code.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=338c30cb225a3a48f71c250affea8623

Comment: Because you've omitted providing an explicit lifetime parameter for the returned `B` in `A::get_f1`, it is assumed to be the same as the only lifetime amongst the inputs. Explicitly state the return type as `-> &mut B<'a>` instead ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9cc2d02571dcb4b8cb9159e4e1e98d24)).

Answer (score 0):

```
    fn get_f1(&mut self) -> &mut B<'a> {
      &mut self.f1
    }
```

you should explicitly define the liftime of the return value of get_f1